# Core data Infinite Drill Down

Tags: core-data

I am currently working on a table list with categories and subcategories, where you can navigate using a drilldown to explore the child categories until you get a detail view.

I got inspiration from iphonesdkarticles.com.

The solution in this blog for the infinite drilldown was populating an array with a plist, and a single UITableView to do the drilldown.

I wanted to use core data with the NSFetchedResultsController instead of the plist. 
I got the first list of categories, but when I click one of them, I got an empty table.

I don't know if using the NSFetchedResultsController in this scenario is the most appropriate solution. Maybe I am doing something wrong when I use didSelectRowatIndex:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Categories *category = (Categories *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


MasterViewController *theViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
theViewController.CurrentLevel += 1;
theViewController.CurrentTitle = categories.name;

detailViewController.category = category;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Something is missing here, please add more of the code.

Comment: You don't appear to be doing anything with the detailViewController.

Comment: That link is no longer relevant. Any updates are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To create infinite drill down in Core Data, just make an entity a relationship of itself.